# Find the optimal cost using Fourier-Motzkin elimination

Tags: linear-programming, fourier-motzkin

> Consider the following linear program $$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset{x_1, x_2} {\text{minimize}} & 50 x_1 + 80 x_2 \\ \text{subject to} & 2 x_1 + 8 x_2 \leq 5 \\ & 6 x_1 + 5 x_2 \leq 10 \\ & x_1, x_2 \geq 0\end{array} $$ Find the optimal cost of this linear program using Fourier-Motzkin elimination.

---

I have already found the feasible region of this problem to be 0 ≤ x1 ≤ 5/3 and 0 <= x2 <= ⅝:

min 50x1 + 80x2

subj 2x1 + 8x2 ≤ 5

6x1 + 5x2 ≤ 10

x1 ≥ 0

x2 ≥ 0

Rewrite constraints as:

0 ≤ 5 - 2x1 - 8x2

0 ≤ 10 - 6x1 - 5x2

x1 ≥ 0

x2 ≥ 0

=>

0 <= 5 - 2x1

0 ≤ 10 - 6x1

x1 ≥ 0

=>

-5 <= -2x1

-10 <= -6x1

x1 >= 0

=>

5/2 >= x1

5/3 >= x1

x1 >= 0

So the feasible range for x1 is 0 ≤ x1 ≤ 5/3.

To find that the feasible range for x2 is indeed 0 <= x2 <= ⅝, repeat the steps above.

Thus, the constraints aren’t empty, and the problem is feasible.

so I think the optimum solution is (0,0) because this is the minimum of both x1 and x2, but I'm not sure if my logic somewhere is wrong.

Comment: Please [read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I MathJax'ed a bit.  Please take care of the rest